# Testing for interactions without fully factorial anova

Tags: anova, interaction

I have an experiment that tests a the mass of 3 litter types (G, F, L) after they have been decomposing for a year. I want to test for interaction effects between the litter types. I have responses for
G,
F,
L,
GF,
GL,
GFL,
but am missing FL.

I test for interactions by making a model with mass ~ G + F+ L and then comparing with mass ~ G + F + L + G:F. However, I get the same model output with mass ~ G + F + L + G:L and with mass ~ G + F + L + G:F which seems very suspicious. Does anyone know why this is happening/how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

1) There is an issue with your code. I haven't seen your code, so I wouldn't be able to help you there. Just something to watch out for.

2) G has very little interaction with either F or L. In other words, using litters G and F together isn't at all very different from using litter G by itself, and using litters G and L together isn't at all very different from using litter G by itself. Thus, the two outputs would be the similar.

Comment: 2) I checked the model outcomes are identical not just similar. Also when I added some fake data for the FL interaction and reran the code, the GL and FL interactions were different from each other

Comment: Here is the code I apologize for the formatting   #base model- no interactions
massBase.lm <- lm(mass~ G + F + L, data)  

#Grass Forb interaction  
massGF.lm <- lm(mass~ G + F + L + G:F, data)  
anova(massBase.lm, massGF.lm)